# Redirect using mod_rewrite issue

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying redirect all requests from `domain.com/sign-up/*`. to domain.com/sign-up/
In addition, I would like to know if my code can be improved, see below.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
Options +Indexes  
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^sign-up/(.*)\.php$ public/register.php [NC] 
RewriteRule ^sign-up/(.*) /sign-up/ [R]
RewriteRule ^sign-up/\??lang=([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z])$ public/register.php?lang=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^sign-up/?$ public/register.php [NC,L]
```

Why no redirect takes place?

Comment: You must share all the cases of the URLs that you want to rewrite. Otherwise all we provide is just guesses. Share the URLs and the process. What happens now, what should happen, how are the URLs now, how should they be?!

Comment: Hi, Everything currently works fine, except the example I mentioned in the question. The RewriteRule that does nothing is: "RewriteRule ^sign-up/(.*) /sign-up/ [R]" If I understand correctly, everything that I'll type e.g domain.com/sign-up/foo should get redirected (not re written) to domain.com/sign-up/

Comment: Doesn't seem to have an effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, and let me know if it works. If not, please let me know for which URL it's not working.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks  
Options +Indexes  
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# sign-up/xxx.php -> public/register.php
RewriteRule ^sign-up/.*\.php$ public/register.php [L] 

# sign-up/xxx -> /sign-up/
RewriteRule ^sign-up/.+ /sign-up/ [R=301,QSA,L]

# sign-up/?lang=xxx -> public/register.php?lang=xxx
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .*lang=([a-z]{3}).* [NC]
RewriteRule ^sign-up/$ public/register.php?lang=%1 [L,NC]

# /sign-up/ -> public/register.php
RewriteRule ^sign-up/?$ public/register.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: # sign-up/xxx -> /sign-up/ RewriteRule ^sign-up/.* /sign-up/ [L,R] seems like the same result I got, no redirection is happening. only rewrite. sign-up/xxx should show sign-up/ in the browser uri

Comment: @user1614199 How about now?

Comment: Same thing, it doesn't redirect. Is there another htaccess redirect based on regex I can use?

Comment: @user1614199 Is this htaccess file on the root of your site? Are these rules the only ones in your file?

Comment: Hi Shef, you're spot on, I forgot to remove the one in the root. Anyway I applied the above rules to the one in the root and made the path corrections, which now /sign-up/xxx results in too many redirects message

Comment: Another too many redirects trigger: sign-up/?lang=eng

Comment: @user1614199 What path corrections did you do? Did you copy the rules as they are currently, or are you using the previous version I had posted?

Comment: Using the current rules (both didn't work), the path corrections I am referring to is changing public/register.php with site_root/public/register.php

Comment: @user1614199 Can you share which URLs are resulting in an infinite redirect?

Comment: example.com/sign-up/?lang=eng & example.com/sign-up/.* basically, everything under sign-up I guess...

Comment: The latest version works, Thanks !, Do you happen to know of a good place to read about mod_rewrite? (other then the official one which lacks)

Comment: @user1614199 Great. I am glad it finally worked. Hmm... unfortunately I haven't found anything that includes all the pieces. I have picked up this skills in my work experience. You need some time to learn this pieces and be able to put them all together. Good luck!

Comment: Hi Shef, seems like something is off Is there a way I can contact you other then SO ? If not, please let me know and I'll explain my self better. my mail is eladchen@gmail.com

Comment: Basically,                                          http://playgnd.com/sign-up works
http://playgnd.com/sign-up/ works
http://playgnd.com/sign-up/xxx works (is redirected to /sign-up/)


http://playgnd.com/sign-up/xxx.php > Not redirected to /sign-up/

Comment: Solved. Thanks anyway.